# Property is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class like this :

```
export class Group {
    id: string;
    name: string = '';
    type: 'local' | 'ldap' = 'local';
    members: number[] = [];
```

I call it in my application.component.ts :

```
    protected localGroups: Group[];
    protected ldapGroups: Group[];
    protected ldapGroupsState: 'unloaded' | 'loading' | 'loaded' = 'unloaded';
    public filteredList = this.localGroups.slice(); <-- gives error "Property localGroups is used before its initialization"
```

My filteredList is used like this :

```
    isFiltered(group: any) {
        return this.filteredList.find(item => item.id === group.id);
    }
```

I don't know how to resolve it.

EDIT :

I want to make a search filter inside a mat-select with mat-select-filter.

HTML :

```
                        <mat-select-filter [array]="localGroups" (filteredReturn)="filteredList=$event"
                            [displayMember]="'name'">
                        </mat-select-filter>
                        <mat-optgroup label="Local">
                            <mat-option id="application-local-groups-{{group.id}}" *ngFor="let group of localGroups"
                                [value]="group" [class.hide]="!isFiltered(group)">{{ group.name }}</mat-option>
                        </mat-optgroup>
```

If I initialize my variables like Michael D's answer, my localGroups disappear.
I need to do a first research to display my local groups.

Comment: Initialize the variables: `protected localGroups: Group[] = [];` and `protected ldapGroups: Group[] = [];`

Comment: @MichaelD is right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but now I have another issue with my HTML. Please check my edit.

Comment: @leyh do you initialize the localGroups anywhere else?

Comment: The only other place I use localGroups is :   this.configService.getAvailableGroups().then((groups: Group[]) => {
            this.localGroups = groups.filter((value) => value.type === 'local');
            this.ldapGroups = groups.filter((value) => value.type === 'ldap');
        });

Comment: That makes total difference. Could you please add that function where that part exists?

Comment: That part is called in my constructor.

Comment: Okay, so try removing the change suggested by Michael, and right before your code in constructor write something like this: `localGroups = [];  ldapGroups = []`...

Comment: But If I remove the change suggested by Michael I got the first problem with the use before initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is self-describing.
You're trying to use property `this.localGroups` but haven't initialized it anywhere.
You have a  few ways to solve the issue.
First one would be modifying your `application.component.ts` to have the following code instead:

```
    protected localGroups: Group[] = []; // <-- Modified this
    protected ldapGroups: Group[] = []; // <-- Modified this
    protected ldapGroupsState: 'unloaded' | 'loading' | 'loaded' = 'unloaded';
    public filteredList = this.localGroups.slice();
```

and the second would be checking for nullness before going forward:
`public filteredList = this.localGroups?.slice() // <-- Pay attention to the '?' here`

Comment: I tried to add the '?' but got the error : "src/app/admin/sbconfig/application.component.ts:45:52 - error TS1005: ':' expected."

Comment: hmm you might be using an older version of typescript. Could you please check the package.json file to see what version of typescript you have?

Comment: I use the version 4.2.3